# Why append method not working with empty array in VueJS

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-nova

I have a component with empty data array

```
data: () => ({
    selectedResource : [],
}),
```

but when i try to add some item to this array i got an error

```
    selectResource(resource){
        console.log(this.selectedResource);
        this.selectedResource.append(resource)
    }
```

> this.selectedResource.append is not a function

Comment: `append()` is a jquery function, use `push()` instead

Comment: this.selectedResource.push is not a function

Comment: where do you use the method? could you show the surrounded code please

Comment: there is a lot of code and i can just upload file to free file-service. http://file.sampo.ru/nnrknd/

Comment: Wont download it here at work sorry, I´ll look into it when home

Answer (score 0):

Using this should work

```
    data() {
        return {
            selectedResource: [],
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $set for add item to array:

```
this.$set(yourArray, 'yourIndex', 'YourValue')
```